# bind_param() truncates input at first non-numeric character

Tags: php, mysqli

This snippet of my PHP code does not output the months, days, hours..etc.
This is the code:

```
$dat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt = $LINK ->prepare("INSERT INTO NewUser VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isss',$dat, $Phone, $User, $Pass);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

And the output in my database is the year only.
[image]

so, what am I missing after following everything written [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: You're passing the date as an integer. Meaning it will interpret only the part of string up to the first non-numerical character.

Comment: You are binding date as an integer, which cause PHP taking only the year part.

Comment: @Johannes No. Actually, it is varchar. If I set it as date on phpmyadmin, It gives me zeros only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always bind parameters as strings. The first argument in `bind_param()` is a list of types. They should all be `s`.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$dat, $Phone, $User, $Pass);
```

When you bind as an integer then PHP will cast the string to an integer. `2021-01-29 11:11:11` will be converted to `2021` because `-` is not a number. The rest of the string will be discarded.

The only time when you should cast something as an integer or as a string is when MySQL can't figure out the correct type. This is 0.001% of all cases.

If you are confused about mysqli API then please learn PDO instead. It is easier for beginners and offers more functionality.

Also, make sure that your column type in the database is `DateTime` not `varchar` or `int`! If you need the current date then use `NOW()` in SQL rather than PHP's `date()`.